# Perl-SQLite3: Basic Question

Tags: perl, sqlite

I admit it's been a while since I've used Perl, but this has me stumped.

Here's the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use DBI;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html><head><title></title></head></body>";

my $login = "admin@xxxxx.com";
my $dbfile = "/var/www/shopsite-data/shopsite_db";
my $sql = qq`SELECT ss_OrderID FROM ss_ORDER WHERE ss_Email=?`;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbfile", "", "") || die "Cannot connect: $DBI::errstr";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($login) or die $sth->errstr();
while (my @result = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
  print "OrderID: $result[0]<br />";
}
$sth->finish;

print "</body>";
print "</html>";
$dbh->disconnect;
```

returns nothing, but I get a resultset when logged in with sqlite3 using the same query. I also get a resultset when I change the query from

```
my $sql = qq`SELECT ss_OrderID FROM ss_ORDER WHERE ss_Email=?`;
```

to

```
my $sql = qq`SELECT ss_OrderID FROM ss_ORDER`;
```

Answer (score 13):

The obvious problem is the @ inside the double quotes:

```
my $login = "admin@xxxxx.com";
```

is probably coming out as

```
 $login = "admin.com"
```

and, if you had warnings switched on, a warning would be printed to the log file, because Perl sees @xxxx as an array and tries to interpolate it, then warns because it is empty. That is, assuming you don't have an array called @xxxx. If you do, then you would get all the values of it in the string.

Where you have the email address, use single quotes around it to prevent @xxxx being interpolated as an array:

```
my $login = 'admin@xxxxx.com';
```

Or you could use

```
my $login = "admin\@xxxxx.com";
```

to prevent the @ starting an interpolation.
There may be other problems with your script but this is the most obvious one.

Strangely enough [I was just reading about drawbacks of interpolation in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751098/are-there-any-drawbacks-to-interpolation-in-perl).

### One more thing ...

One more thing: you already have fatalsToBrowser, but

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser warningsToBrowser);
```

would probably have given you a warning on your browser about uninitialized values, so it might be worth turning `warningsToBrowser` on until your script seems to be working (or if it stops working again) ([documentation here](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Carp.html#MAKING-WARNINGS-APPEAR-AS-HTML-COMMENTS)), and the other two on always.

Comment: No warning would be issued because he has not enabled warnings.

Comment: I've altered the post as you suggested.

Comment: Agreed; he is missing `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 4):

I believe [Kinopiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752859/perl-sqlite3-basic-question/1752971#1752971) already pinpointed the problem.

I will add that, if you are going to use `CGI.pm`, you should not generate headers by hand. Instead, use `CGI::header`.

Also:

```
print "<html><head><title></title></head></body>";
```

Note the closing tag for `body` when you meant to use an opening tag.

Last, but definitely not least, you should

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

in your scripts.

Comment: Kinopiko & Sinan,

Many thanks to both of you. I am indeed rusty on perl.